Add a new row in a table and then adding or pasting information in that same row
I have and excel where in a sheet there is a table with information, in another sheet I want to create a form that could allow me to add new information to that table
Here is an example of more of less how my table is

I have been able to add a new row to that table with this macro
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim tbl As ListObject

Set ws = ActiveSheet

Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Prueba")

tbl.ListRows.Add   '' This line will add a row at the end of the table

However I haven't found a way to add information to the row that was added

Looping Through Cells of Newly Added Row in Excel Table
Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Prueba")
    Dim lr As ListRow: Set lr = tbl.ListRows.Add
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = lr.Range
    ' Or you could skip a few variables:
    'Set rg = tbl.ListRows.Add.Range
    'Set rg = ws.ListObjects("Prueba").ListRows.Add.Range
    'Set rg = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Prueba").ListRows.Add.Range
    
    Dim c As Long
    
    For c = 1 To rg.Columns.Count
        rg.Cells(c).Value = c
    Next c
    
    ' Or just using 'c' variable
'    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Prueba").ListRows.Add.Range
'        For c = 1 To .Columns.Count
'            .Cells(c).Value = c
'        Next c
'    End With

End Sub

Another Scenario

A simple example where the 'populated' rows from Sheet2 starting with cell A2 are copied to newly added rows of table Prueba in Sheet1. Both sheets are in the workbook containing this code (ThisWorkbook).
It could be improved i.e. shortened and made more efficient but the aim here is to show how to reference the various objects (workbooks, worksheets, ranges, listobjects, listrows, ...), to loop through cells of a range and copy rows from one worksheet to a table on another worksheet.

Sub Test2()
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source (single-column) range ('srg').
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim slcell As Range: Set slcell = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    Dim srg As Ranges: Set srg = sws.Range("A2", slcell)
    
    ' Reference the destination table ('dlo').
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim dlo As ListObject: Set dlo = dws.ListObjects("Prueba")
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim dlr As ListRow, drrg As Range, srrg As Range, scell As Range
    
    ' Loop through each cell in the source range.
    For Each scell In srg.Cells
        ' Add a row to the table and reference its range ('drg').
        Set dlr = dlo.ListRows.Add
        Set drrg = dlr.Range
        ' Reference the source (single) row range ('srrg').
        Set srrg = scell.Resize(, drrg.Columns.Count)
        ' Write the values from the source row range
        ' to the destination (single) row range
        ' (they are of the same size due to the previous line).
        drrg.Value = srrg.Value
    Next scell

End Sub 


Thank You! With this macro , I can also add information to the new row?

rg is the range of the new row. The example loop is adding the integers from 1 to the number of columns of the range (table). Instead of the loop, you could add values from user form's text boxes to the first two cells with something like rg.Cells(1).Value = txtID.Value: rg.Cells(2).Value = txtName.Value. You could also fill the whole row e.g. starting with a cell in another worksheet with e.g. rg.Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A5").Resize(, rg.Columns.Count).Value.

So my code will end up like this ?                                                                           Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Prueba")
Dim lr As ListRow: Set lr = tbl.ListRows.Add
Dim rg As Range: Set rg = lr.Range                                                                         For c = 1 To rg.Columns.Count                                                                               rg.Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A5").Resize(, rg.Columns.Count).Value

Without For c = 1 To rg.Columns.Count. And the cell (A5) could be any cell.

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Prueba") Dim lr As ListRow: Set lr = tbl.ListRows.Add Dim rg As Range: Set rg = lr And then Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A5").Resize(, rg.Columns.Count).Value If the information is in another sheet I do have to select it first?

It's Set rg = lr.Range. You don't have to select anything since the other sheet is referenced with Worksheets("Sheet2"). or more accurately, ws.Parent.Worksheets("Sheet2"). (if both sheets are in the same workbook). You forgot rg.Value = i.e. rg.Value = ws.Parent.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A5").Resize(, rg.Columns.Count).Value.

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Prueba") Dim lr As ListRow: Set lr = tbl.ListRows.Add Dim rg As Range: Set rg = lr.Range Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A5").Resize(, rg.Columns.Count).Value And if I want to add more than one data I just add another line like this one Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A6").Resize(, rg.Columns.Count).Value

No, you have to add another row first with e.g. Set lr = tbl.ListRows.Add: Set rg = lr.Range: and only then rg.Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A6").Resize(, rg.Columns.Count).Value. I'll add an example with a loop to my post shortly.

Is there a way to add more data in the same row , but diferents values?
